# Finding other products according to the given products

Tags: sql, sql-server, product

Let me inform you about the database. it contains data about sales of the supermarket. I think I need just 2 tables, products and sales. needed columns of sales are sales_date, and sales_code. product_name and price should be used from the product table. Product_code is my foreign key. sales_code is basically a sales check. Sales codes are the same for products that were sold together. I mean if you have bought some goods,  your sales code is the same for all goods which you bought.

I should find the products 'Bismak 200gr' and 'energizer maximum' which two were bought together, and other goods were bought together with them. I draw the scheme.[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR4rP.jpg) I don't know how I can implement it. I have written some codes.

```
select products.product_name as goods, sum(price) as price, sales_code from sales

inner join products on sales.product_code = products.product_code
where product_name like  '%Bismak 200gr waflim%'
or  product_name like '%energizer maximum%'

group by  product_name,products.price, sales_code
```

result should be like this:

| product_name | price | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bismak 200gr waflim | 12.39 | 2019-07-1912:29:00.000 |
| energizer maximum | 25.4 | 2019-07-1912:30:00.000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

sample data:

[sales table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsbuV.png)

[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNo2i.png)

after comments, i chanced my query. and it works
SELECT sales.sales_code,sales_date,product_name
FROM sales

inner join

(  SELECT sales_code
FROM  sales s
inner join  products p on s.product_code = p.product_code
WHERE
p.product_name like '%Bismak 200gr waflim%' or
p.product_name like '%energizer maximum%'
GROUP BY sales_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.product_name like '%Bismak 200gr waflim%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 2

) s

on s.sales_code = sales.sales_code
inner join products on products.product_code = sales.product_code

Comment: So you need all the sales that contain two (or more) specified product codes?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @George Menoutis
yes, I need all the sales. I know the names of two products that were sold. according to them, I need to find other products which were sold together. imagine that you are a customer, you've bought some products. you got sales check.  after 2 days you realize that you forget to take one of your products.  also, you lost the sales check. but you remember you've bought let's say 'energizer maximum' and 'Bismak 200gr waflim' and some other products together. corresponding to these products I need to find others.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find the sales codes where one of the products is X and another of the products is Y

```
SELECT sales_code
FROM 
  sales s
  inner join 
  products p on s.product_code = p.product_code
WHERE 
  p.product_name like '%Bismak 200gr waflim%' or  
  p.product_name like '%energizer maximum%'
GROUP BY sales_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.product_name like '%Bismak 200gr waflim%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 2
```

You could then join this back to your sales table to find all the other products sold at the same time, in the same sales codes

The HAVING enforces that both kinds of product be present in a sales code. It would be simpler if your product names were consistent, but the way you've written your query leads me to believe that you might have eg "energiser maximum size 1" and "energiser maximum size 2" etc and want to limp them all together. If your descriptions are consistent, you can ditch the LIKE and do `COUNT(DISTINCT product_name)`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to check all sales who have all of the items by aggregation adding per-product flags,
then use them as semi-join in your original query:

```
select 
     products.product_name as goods
    ,sum(price) as price
    ,sales_code 
from 
    sales s
    inner join products p on s.product_code = p.product_code
where s.sales_code in
(
    select sales_code 
    from sales
    group by sales_code
    having 
        2=
        sign(sum(case when p.product_name like '%Bismak 200gr waflim%' then 1 else 0 end))
        +
        sign(sum(case when p.product_name like '%energizer maximum%' then 1 else 0 end))
)
group by  p.product_name,p.price,s.sales_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query which will find all pairs of products bought together.
We use `<` in the join to only say "A bought at the same time as B" and not "B bought at the same time as A" which would be a duplicate (and also to avoid saying "A bought at the same time as A"!)

> ```
> create table products (productName varchar(10), price int);
> insert into products values ('A',1),('B',2),('C',3);
> CREATE TABLE sales(salesCode int, salesDate date default current_timestamp, product varchar(10));
> insert into sales (salesCode, product) values (1,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'B'),(2,'C');
> SELECT
>  COUNT(*)"number",
>  a.product,
>  b.product
> FROM sales a
> JOIN sales b
> ON a.salesCode = b.salesCode
> AND a.product < b.product
> GROUP BY
>  a.product,
>  b.product
> ORDER BY
>  a.product,
>  b.product;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> number | product | product
> -----: | :------ | :------
>      1 | A       | B      
>      1 | B       | C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a98bf560130d89a9daa3826318b57643)*